# Access sharepoint search rest api

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, sharepoint

I have a problem. I use Azure AD to authenticate my asp.net app. Authentication works fine. Then I from this app trying to access OneDrive for Business using sharepoint search rest api. But the server always receives a response with a 401 error. I understand that the problem is in the access token which I use (Now I use the token received from Azure AD). But I never found the normal description of how to obtain an access token for the sharepoint search rest api.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer

You need to give your ASP.NET Application permission to use your OneDrive for Business application.

Here is an overview of how to do this using the Azure Management Portal. (Note that your OneDrive for Business account is a type of Office 365 SharePoint Online account.)

Go to manage.windowsazure.com > Active Directory > Your Tenant. If your tenant has an associated OneDrive for Business account, then its list of applications will include **Office 365 SharePoint Online.**

[image: A tenant with an associated Office 365 SharePoint Online account.]

If your tenant's list of application does include Office 365 SharePoint Online, then your next step is to give your ASP.NET Web Application permission to access it.

Open up your Web Application's page in the Azure Active Directory area. Then choose CONFIGURE > Add Application. Add the Office 365 SharePoint Online application. Give it all necessary permissions and save.

The following screenshot is for a Native Client Application, because that is what my demo code is using. You can do a similar thing for a Web Application, though you will need to use an X509 Certificate for authentication instead of a username/password.

[image: Permissions for a Native Client App to access SharePoint Search REST]

Your access token will now work with your Office 365 for Business account. Hooray!

## Demo

Here is some sample code that works on my machine with a Native Client App. You can do the same thing with a Web Application, though you will need to use an X509 Certificate instead of a username/password.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Net;

namespace AAD_SharePointOnlineApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var authContext =
                new AuthenticationContext(Constants.AUTHORITY);

            var userCredential = 
                new UserCredential(Constants.USER_NAME, Constants.USER_PASSWORD);

            var result = authContext
                .AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.RESOURCE, Constants.CLIENT_ID_NATIVE, userCredential)
                .Result;

            var token = result.AccessToken;

            var url = "https://mvp0.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27timesheets%27";
            var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token);
            var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }
    }

    class Constants
    {
        public const string AUTHORITY =
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mvp0.onmicrosoft.com/";
    
        public const string RESOURCE =
            "https://mvp0.sharepoint.com";

        public const string CLIENT_ID_NATIVE = 
            "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx";

        public const string USER_NAME = 
            "MY_USER@mvp0.onmicrosoft.com";

        public const string USER_PASSWORD = 
            "MY_PASSWORD";
    }
}
```

## Comments

If you are trying to do the above with a Web Application instead of a Native Client Application, then you will need to use an X509 Certificate, otherwise you will receive the following error.

> Unsupported app only token.

See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2015/05/03/performing-app-only-operations-on-sharepoint-online-through-azure-ad.aspx